# Random Number in a loop jquery

Tags: jquery, loops, random, numbers

I would for every loop an other random number, but it does not want worke...
I don't know why.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        setTimeout("execute()",5000);

    })

    function execute(){
        for(i=0;i<=5;i++){
            var zWindow = $(window).height();
            var yWindow = $(window).width();
            var z=Math.floor((Math.random() * zWindow) + 1);
            var y=Math.floor((Math.random() * yWindow) + 1);
            $("#egg").css({
                "top": z,
                "left": y
            });
            $("#egg").delay(1000).fadeIn(10).delay(3000).fadeOut(100);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Whats the point of the loop*5 in your `execute()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For stopping an interval, use the `clearInterval()`- function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var timesRun = 0; 
    var interval = setInterval(execute, 5000); //only use functionname here

    function execute(){

        timesRun += 1;
        var zWindow = $(window).height();
        var yWindow = $(window).width();

        var z = Math.floor((Math.random() * zWindow) + 1);
        var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * yWindow) + 1);

        $("#egg").css({
            "top": z,
            "left": y
        });
        $("#egg").delay(1000).fadeIn(10).delay(3000).fadeOut(100);

        if(timesRun === 5){
            clearInterval(interval);
        }

     }
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1na2bsxb/2/)

**Reference**

[JS Timing](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You need ***setInterval*** but not ***setTimeout*** which will only execute once:

```
// and use execute directly instead of "execute()"
setInterval(execute, 5000);
```

Comment: but now it runs over and over, i want just 5 Times :)